# How To Register Services For Custom .Net Core Middleware

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependencies, startup, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm currently trying to understand and work with custom middleware in DotNet Core.

According to the Microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> Middleware should follow the Explicit Dependencies Principle by exposing its dependencies in its constructor.

So if I follow this principle, I end up with something like this

**Explicit Dependency Version**

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderFeatureHeaderExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseFeatureHeaders(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> builder)
        {
            return app.UseMiddleware<FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware>(builder);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    private Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> _builder;
    private FeaturePolicyStringBuilder _builderInstance;

    public FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> builder, FeaturePolicyStringBuilder builderInstance)
    {
        _next = next;
        _builderInstance = builderInstance;
        _builder = builder;
        _builder(_builderInstance);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var header = _builderInstance.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader();
        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header.Key))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(_builderInstance.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader());
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Here the FeaturePolicyStringBuilder is being provided as a service and has been registered in the startup file.

---

**The Other Version (Using New)**

```
  public class FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    private Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> _builder;
    private FeaturePolicyStringBuilder _builderInstance;

    public FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> builder)
    {
        _next = next;
        _builderInstance = new FeaturePolicyStringBuilder();
        _builder = builder;
        _builder(_builderInstance);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var header = _builderInstance.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader();
        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header.Key))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(_builderInstance.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader());
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

In this version I am simply "Newing Up" the dependency, meaning that I don't have to register it as a service, this makes it easier to encapsulate into it's own project.
(Im not sure really how evil this is a it seems to me I'm already tightly coupled to the FeaturePolicyStringBuilder due to the Action requiring it as a type, so why not more glue!)

**The Question**
Is there a way to still follow the Explicit Dependencies Principle while not having to explicitly register those dependencies with the Service Provider? or some way to register them within the middlware component itself?

Thanks!

P.S: I have added the builder code below so that the purpose of the code is more clear: as per gerry.inc's comment

```
public class FeaturePolicyStringBuilder
{
    private string _featurePolicyString;

    public KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> CreateFeaturePolicyHeader()
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("feature-policy", _featurePolicyString);
    }

    private void CreateDirective(string directiveName, Action<SourceBuilder> builder)
    {
        var builderObj = new SourceBuilder();
        builder(builderObj);
        _featurePolicyString += $"{directiveName} '{builderObj.GetPrefix()}' {builderObj.GetSources()};";
    }

    public FeaturePolicyStringBuilder Camera(Action<SourceBuilder> builder)
    {
        CreateDirective("camera", builder);
        return this;
    }

    public FeaturePolicyStringBuilder Accelerometer(Action<SourceBuilder> builder)
    {
        CreateDirective("accelerometer", builder);
        return this;
    }

    public FeaturePolicyStringBuilder Battery(Action<SourceBuilder> builder)
    {
        CreateDirective("battery", builder);
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

### What the call in the Configure method looks like

```
app.UseFeatureHeaders(x => 
            x.Camera(b =>
            b.AddPrefix(HeaderPrefixEnum.HeaderPrefix.Self)
                .AddSource("Test"))
            .Accelerometer(b => 
                b.AddPrefix(HeaderPrefixEnum.HeaderPrefix.Self)
                    .AddSource("Test")
                    .AddSource("Test")
                    .AddPrefix(HeaderPrefixEnum.HeaderPrefix.None)
                    .AddPrefix(HeaderPrefixEnum.HeaderPrefix.Src)));
```

Comment: Why would you want to NOT register with the Service Provider? and also what exactly does `_builderInstance.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader()` do? I assume it produces a key value pair to be added to response headers, but is it more than just `return new Kvp("Header","Value")`? Im tempted to think the options pattern can help, but im not so sure what exactly your code does.

Comment: @gerryc.inc I have added the builder code so you can see more clearly how it works, essentially I am trying to create a FeatureHeaderBuilder similar to how NWebsec https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/ works.  I wanted specifically to understand how a builder can provide a fluent lamda style configuration.  Note I DO want to register with the service provider. But I'm looking for a way to do so without explicitly adding it in services.Add<> if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way the builder is being configured, then the builder and configuration action should be invoked before adding the middleware

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderFeatureHeaderExtension {

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseFeatureHeaders(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<FeaturePolicyStringBuilder> configureBuilder) {
        FeaturePolicyStringBuilder builder = new FeaturePolicyStringBuilder();
        configureBuilder?.Invoke(builder);
        var header = builder.CreateFeaturePolicyHeader();
        return app.UseMiddleware<FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware>(header);
    }
}
```

And the middleware refactored accordingly

```
public class FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware {
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    private KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> header;

    public FeaturePolicyHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> header) {
        _next = next;
        this.header = header;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header.Key)) {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(header);
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

This DRY approach allows for better separation of concerns and explicitly indicates what the middleware actual needs to perform its function.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Nkosi This solution certainly helps to make the middleware itself follow the Explicit Dependencies Rule as now all of its dependencies are provided by the extension method.  However I'm still confused as to how I can register these dependencies to be injected by the .Net Core IOC container, so I could encapsulate this into its own library and have those dependencies created for me by the startup class. Any ideas?

Comment: @AFM-Horizon I don't understand your request. The middleware and extension can live in its own library and called by startup class. Because of how you want to configure the middleware's dependency, there really is no need to include the container. This is still Pure DI.

Comment: So I gues what you are saying is that there is no way of avoiding the new keyword in the extension?,  and further when you say it is still pure DI you are refering to the fact that we are creating the dependencies at the highest level possible and passing them down to the lower level classes?  So this method is still following the Explicit Dependencies Principle?

Comment: @AFM-Horizon Yes it is possible to inject the builder into the application service collection, but based on how you use it, it does not need to be added since it is only needed at the extension method's level. And that would also require multiple steps (add to services then call add midddleware) while this approach requires only one based on what you have shown. Yes it still follows explicit dependency principle.